# make some listView's rows invisible

Tags: listview, button, android-activity, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

In my Activity, I created a **listView** by somebody's post here.

Each listView's **row** contains **TextView and Button**.

By some condition, I would like to make a few rows buttons **invisible** in runtime but I can't understand how.

```
for (int listIndex = 0; listIndex < booksNamesList.size(); ++listIndex) {

    // get the book name from the list and add it to the listAdapter

    String strBookName = booksNamesList.get(listIndex).getBookText().toString();

    m_listAdapter.add(strExperience);

    // TODO:
    // if *anyCondition*, disable the button for the listIndex row.

}

m_listView.setAdapter( m_listAdapter );
```

NOTE: m_listView is an object of ListView, m_listAdapter is an object of ArrayAdapter.

please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded to do so by using ViewHolder pattern. there are examples in stackoverflow so it wasn't difficult at all.
In View Holder pattern, you should define your views and there's a method named 'getView' that is called for each list row. then, it's easy to handle the rows.. you can set the view visibility to GONE or whatever :)